# Video plays in VLC gui but not when using python libvlc

Tags: python, linux, vlc, libvlc

I'm creating a python script that plays mp3/cdg karaoke files. I can open these files and they play with no problems when using the standalone VLC gui, however when I use the python libvlc library to open them, they play for a few frames then stop while the audio continues.

I'm almost certain that this is is because the gui has some configuration set that the python implementation is defaulting to something else, but I'm not sure what it is. 
My question is:
A) is there some way to just "export" the settings from the gui to command line arguments so I can pass them to the python implementation?
B) If not, is there some way to compare the settings each one is using?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you only have one copy of libvlc and that it's current.

You can see what options VLC is using to play the file by clicking the "show more options" in the "Open Media" dialog.